# How do I convert this PHP function to recursively search my directories?

Tags: php

I have this code right now:

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "./";

//get all image files with a .m4v/.mp4 extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.{m4v,mp4,mkv}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

What's the quickest way to convert this to recursively search any subdirectory for the same file types?

Comment: do you mean that there are n  subdirectories inside current directory and you need to search recursively particular files?

Answer (score 0):

- You could walk to manual and get from user comments recursive function. [glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php)
- You could use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

---

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));
$images = array();
foreach ($objects as $name => $object)
    {
    /* @var $object SplFileInfo */
    if (in_array($object->getExtension(), array('m4v', 'mp4', 'mkv')))
        $images[] = $name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function RecursiveGetfiles($dir)
{
  $files=array();
  foreach(glob('$dir/*') as $d)
  {
      if(is_dir($d))
      {
         $files[]=RecursiveGetfiles($d);
      }
  }
  $files=glob($directory . "*.{m4v,mp4,mkv}", GLOB_BRACE);
  return $files;

}
```